# I have problem about use ForeColor to set color for textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have RadGrid with function SelectedIndexChanged ,in this function I want to fill data to textbox with red color when just click at row index 1 . I tried using "If - else" . In "If" i set color to red and "else" is Black by ForeColor .
when I click row index 1 ,it working but when i click row other index the color is not change although data is fill correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the relevant code and look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask to help ask the question in the best way,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.